# customer session does not work except customer page - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, session, customer-session, magento2.0.8

**app/code/Vendore/Module/Block**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class CustomerLink extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_customersession;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_customersession=$session;
    }        
    public function sessionCheck()
    {
        return $this->_customersession->isLoggedIn();
    }

}
```

**app/code/Vendore/Module/view/frontend/template**

```
<?php
if($block->sessionCheck())
{
    echo 'logged in';
}
else
{
    echo 'logged out';
}
?>
```

It works only in **customer** page and **checkout/cart** page, remaining page it return false even customer logged in.

so I decided to use `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext` this return right boolean value in entire website but how to get customer details using `httpContext`.

why **\Magento\Customer\Model\Session** is only working in customer page?

**note:** all caches are in enable mode.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To have access to real data in Magento 2 session you have to apply one of the following

- Do it on non-cacheable page.
- Disable full page cache.
- Set `$this->$_isScopePrivate = true` for block where you are trying to access session.

**Why:**

Magento 2 is rendering public and private content for cacheable pages separately.

During cacheable page rendering Magento is cleaning all data that can be specific to a particular user (unsetting private data). Then separate ajax request is performed to load all private information and update blocks.

That's why session is empty during rendering.

The responsibility of cleaning private data lies on several depersonalization plugins. Customer session for example is cleaned by **\Magento\Customer\Model\Layout\DepersonalizePlugin**.

You can see conditions in which depersonalization will apply in **\Magento\PageCache\Model\DepersonalizeChecker::checkIfDepersonalize**

**What are cacheable/non-cacheable pages:**

In short words, cacheable page is any page that does not include non-cacheable blocks (blocks with `cacheable="false"` attribute in layout declaration). Correspondingly, pages with non-cacheable blocks are non-cacheable. :)

Here you can find the actual check: **\Magento\Framework\View\Layout::isCacheable**

Cacheable page examples: Category, Product view pages, CMS pages

Non-cacheable page examples: Customer account and checkotu pages

There is a more detailed [Magento 2 Caching Overview by Alan Kent](https://alankent.me/2014/12/09/magento-2-caching-overview/)

Comment: great explanation!

Comment: @SergeyIvashchenko where I add this `$this->$_isScopePrivate = true` , I added this code on __construct but getting this error **PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in**

you mean `$this->_isScopePrivate = true;` instead ?

Comment: Yes, this was a typo. It should have been `$this->_isScopePrivate`. Note that this variable is deprecated and it should not be used. Instead, all Blocks should be made cacheable and the documented procedure of Private Content should be followed to add session-specific data to pages: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155606/public-private-content

Comment: After disable the FPC , it work's fine but on live site we should enable the FPC. please suggest the solution

Comment: What is the best solution to get customer data in custom module. I don't want to use **cacheable="false"**. Please let me know the solution.

Comment: If you need this data for porpuses other than rendering - it's ok to just retrieve the data before depersonalization (i.e. before layout XML generation)

Answer (score 1):

That does not seem to be an issue since Magento 2 cleans the session storage for cacheable requests in order to avoid caching of customer private content. In short, you should not access the customer session data, while processing the GET request intended to render the cacheable page.

I would also **not recommend disabling the cache** for the whole page via layout update as a workaround.

Magento 2 provides a special approach to work with a customer private content.
You can find more details in [Magento DevDocs: Private Content](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html) section.