# Why Customer Session is not working on full page cache?

Tags: magento2, login, magento-2.2.5, full-page-cache, customer-session

This is my code below

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();    
$customerSession = $objectManager-create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

   if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) 

   {

       $customerSession->getCustomerId();  // get Customer Id
        $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
        $customerSession->getCustomer();
        $customerSession->getCustomerData();

   }
```

I'm facing a problem when full page cache is `enable` on `disable` it's working fine.

Comment: Where are you using this code and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using this code in phtml file to open a popup form after login

Comment: The following might help: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145851/customer-session-does-not-work-except-customer-page-magento-2

Comment: I have faced this problem before. Solution is please do not use objectManager. Create function in helper or block and use that.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if not working.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use the factory method when **FPC is enabled**.

### By Factory Method :

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
*/
protected $_customerSessionFactory;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory
    ....
) 
{
    ....
    $this->_customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;
    ....
}

public function getCustomerId(){
  $customer = $this->_customerSessionFactory->create();
  echo $customer->getCustomer()->getId();
}
```

### By Object Manager :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerSession = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

echo $customerSession->getCustomerId();
```

Comment: I have tried above code but still not working

Comment: Did you remove generated folder? and flush cache

Comment: Yes i did still same issue

Answer (score 6):

You can give a try to below code:

**1). Using Object Manager**

```
$ObjectManager= \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$context = $ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
return $isLoggedIn;
```

**2). DI way**

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
*/
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface       $customerRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
) 
{
   $this->request = $request;
   $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
   $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
   parent::__construct($context);
}

   public function getCustomerId(){
   $customer = $this->_customerSession->create();
   var_dump($customer->getCustomer()->getId());
}
```

It will work even FPC is enabled.

Comment: Works like charm ;)

Answer (score 1):

```php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

\\Use create instead get in object manager

$customerSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

echo $customerSession->getCustomerId();
```