# Customer session isLoggedIn() not working properly due to the Magento Cache

Tags: magento2.3, ajax, customer-session, logging

I am checking **if customer is logged in or not(also i have to display customer name)** but sometimes it's not working and after flushing block_html cache it works.

I have tried all possible solutions:-

**Tried following but still getting issue:-**

[Why Customer Session is not working on full page cache?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252142/why-customer-session-is-not-working-on-full-page-cache)

https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-get-customer-session-data-when-a-cache-is-enabled-in-magento-2/

As i R&D and found throgh AJAX technique it can be resolved but not any idea of the same...here are the references:-

https://belvg.com/blog/customer-data-management-in-magento-2.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html#configure-page-variations

So please help me for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin

It's the plugin

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin/blob/357bf798252c32517307c2775572c332652f510f/Plugin/Magento/Customer/CustomerData/Customer.php#L43

```
    $result['is_logged_in'] = $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
```

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin/blob/357bf798252c32517307c2775572c332652f510f/view/frontend/templates/index/index.phtml#L1-L11

```
<div class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
    <!-- ko if: customer().is_logged_in  -->
    <span class="logged-in"
            data-bind="text: new String('<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome back %1', '%1')) ?>').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: customer().is_logged_in  -->
    <span class="not-logged-in"
            data-bind='html:"<?= $block->escapeHtml(__("Please <a href='%1'>login</a>", $block->getUrl('customer/account/login'))) ?>"'>
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Take a look at the how I've used the customer binding and knockout

Comment: thanks a ton...it's working for me.

Comment: For the Mega Menu Section:-                                                                                                
i am showing some "static menu" in the Mega Menu section through phtml for logged-in customer only...but for that i have to include your '<div class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">' before my menu <li> due to that design get scattered...so is there any way to avoid using this div scope ? if m not using this div then your code doesn't work.

Comment: You can use it on other elements. But beyond that you might have to have two versions the menu maybe

Comment: Okay, i got that element must be there and i have to adjust it some where else..thankyou so much.