# Check on logged in customer, only working on cart page; why?

Tags: magento2, customer-session

The check is as follows:

The Following code is supposed to check if a customer is logged in anywhere

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

Comment: this is working or not

Comment: It works only when visiting the cart page; in any other pages it does not; however the template where the check is stored,  shows in all pages

Comment: You can't access if the page is cached because of magento unset session for cached page. You can access this way shopping cart, checkout, customer account page. Avoid to use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145851/customer-session-does-not-work-except-customer-page-magento-2

Comment: Hi Sohel; is there then not possible to check that on any page?

Comment: You can use customer data or ajax for this case. But check @BilalUsean answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the why part is in this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/145893/36463)

> During cacheable page rendering Magento is cleaning all data that can be specific to a particular user (unsetting private data). Then separate ajax request is performed to load all private information and update blocks.

You can check the login by `httpContext` it works in all the pages.

```
private $httpContext;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
) {
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
}

public function isLoggedIn()
{
    $isLoggedIn = $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    return $isLoggedIn;
}
```

Comment: This is returning blank on the checkout page, somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace

> $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

with

> $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

When user is logged in, it returns 1 and when not, it returns blank.

Working for me.