# Magento 2.3: Customer ID from Session Returning NULL with Cache Enabled

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, customer-session

I'm calling the following helper but `getCustomerId` is returning NULL when I have cache enabled.  If I disable all cache, then I can return the customer's ID.

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
  private $_customerSession;

  public function __construct (
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
  ) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
  }

  public function getCustomerId()
  {
    return $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
  }
}
```

I've also tried `return $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();` which also returns NULL

---

Now if I inject the Object Manager instead, I get my desired result and it returns the customerId even with cache enabled:

```
...
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
  ) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
  }

  public function isBrandingCustomer()
  {
    $customerSession = $this->_objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");
    return $customerSession->getCustomerId();
  }
...
```

So my question is, How can I return the customer's ID from `$customerSession` with cache enabled and without using Object Manager?

Comment: Have a look around this will helps you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261649/check-on-logged-in-customer-only-working-on-cart-page-why/261654#261654

Answer (score 0):

You need to first be aware how to Magento cache work. You can't use customer ID in cachable pages. Why? Cause when you have unique version of website for every user - it is not from cache.

By default Magento 2 cache hash doesn't include customer ID. So you have wrong approach. You can use customer ID only on non-cached pages as cart/checkout or during order progress or customer section.

For rest of cases you should change your approach. You should display this content using JavaScript. There is special feature for it in Magento. You can use `customerData`. Magento makes AJAX request about sections when user is logged. Then this content is saved in localStorage. You can add plugin and inject there your extra customer attribute. Then you will have access to it from javascript level.

When you really need to use it in PHP, then you need to modify magento cache hash. Then you can e.g prepare another cache for Gender `male` and another for gender `female`. But unique cache for ID => is not a cache :)